# Taking limits with respect to the Hausdorff metric does not preserve measure

Tags: limits, measure-theory, metric-spaces, hausdorff-distance

In [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.07141), in the introduction, the authors say:

> "Disproportionate divisions are easily seen to exist when all the demands are rational...  However, this does notimmediately demonstrate existence for irrational demands, since **taking limits with respect to the Hausdorff metric**, for example, **does not preserve measure**".

The context is a partition of the unit interval $[0,1]$ into sub-intervals. I am trying to understand the emphasized sentence. Does it mean that there exists an infinite sequence of subsets of $[0,1]$, say $X_1,X_2,\ldots,$, and another subset $X\subseteq [0,1]$, and a measure $\mu$, such that:

- The [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) between $X_n$ and $X$ approaches $0$ when $n\to\infty$, but -
- The measure $\mu(X_n)$ does not approach the measure $\mu(X)$ when $n\to\infty$?

If so, what is an example of such a sequence?

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist sorry, I forgot to clean up, fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $[0,1]$ let $X_n$ be the finite set
$$
X_n = \left\{\frac{k}{n} : 0 \le k \le n\right\}
$$
Then $X_n$ converges to $[0,1]$ in the Haudsdorff metric, even though each $X_n$ has measure $0$ and $[0,1]$ has measure $1$.